# Sufficient condition of a projection operator P on a Hilbert space H

Tags: hilbert-spaces

In a Hilbert space, is the idempotence condition of an operator P sufficient to assert that the operator is a projection operator or is it necessary that the operator is also self-adjoint?

Comment: Self-adjointness is necessary to have an *orthogonal* projection. You may also be willing to consider arbitrary idempotents as not-necessarily-orthogonal projections.

Comment: Do you want just a projection, or an orthogonal projection?

Comment: @lisyarus Just a projection.  As QiaochuYuan has said, for the projection to be orthogonal it is necessary for the operator to also be self-adjoint. My doubt is, do non-orthogonal projections exist in a Hilbert space and therefore idempotence is a sufficient condition? I am sorry if my question is a bit silly but I have not worked much with Hilbert spaces and in all the cases I have seen the projection operators have been idempotent and self-adjoint.

Comment: @Mario $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: @Mario Yes, there are many projection operators in any Hilbert space (and in fact just a vector space), including non-orthogonal ones. Idempotency is essentially equivalent to being a projection operator, and if the operator isn't self-adjoint, the projection won't be orthogonal.

Comment: Thank to all. My doubts have been clarified.